# How do I install a .sdb file with the command prompt?

Tags: cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm trying to configure Windows so UAC doesn't ask permission every time I open Winamp. I created a .sdb file for Winamp that runs it as invoker and gives it write permissions and saved it at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp compatability fix.sdb
```

Then, from what I've read I should be able to run cmd as an administrator and use the command:

```
sdbinst.exe -q C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp compatability fix.sdb
```

to install it.

However, when I do that, I get this:

```
Error: Too many command-line arguments.

Usage: sdbinst [-?] [-q] [-u] [-g] [-p] [-n[:WIN32 |WIN64]] myfile.sdb | <guid> | "name"

   -? - print this help text.

   -p - Allow SDBs containing patches.

   -q - Quiet mode: prompts are auto-accepted.

   -u -Uninstall.

   -g <guid> - GUID of file <uninstall only>.

   -n "name" - Internal name of file <uninstall only>.
```

So what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you change the properties of Winamp to run as Admin?  Will that suffice?

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding the path with quotes, as such:

```
sdbinst.exe -q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp compatability fix.sdb"
```